# How to set Zero Subtotal Checkout after applying coupon, which makes grand total to 0

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, zero-subtotal

In my project at admin panel I have set Store->Configuration->Sales->Payment Method->Ccavenuepay and Minimum Order Total to 1 or 0.1.

On checkout page when I apply the discount coupon, my grand total becomes zero. In that case, it should show message **No Payment Information Required** as per set in admin panel. but it shows **No payment methods available** message. And when I refresh the page then it shows No Payment Information Required and then after a second shows all payment method which I am using. Can somebody please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It *could* possibly be the same issue that I've had before where Free Shipping is calculated on the base subtotal with tax included *before* the discount is applied. I've made a little rewrite to fix that below. I hope the fix works for your issue too!

**app/code/local/MyCompany/FreeShippingAfterDiscount/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Freeshipping.php**

```
<?php

class MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Freeshipping
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping
{

    /**
    * FreeShipping Rates Collector
    *
    * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
    *
    * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
    */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

        $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

        #Custom line
        $valueAfterDiscount = ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() - $request->getPackageValue()) + $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount();

        if (($request->getFreeShipping())
            || ($valueAfterDiscount >=
                $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
        ) {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice('0.00');
            $method->setCost('0.00');

            $result->append($method);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/MyCompany/FreeShippingAfterDiscount/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <freeshippingafterdiscount>
                <class>MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount_Model</class>
            </freeshippingafterdiscount>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <carrier_freeshipping>MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Freeshipping</carrier_freeshipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_FreeShippingAfterDiscount>
    </modules>
</config>
```